# Executing Webpack bundlers in sequence

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'll start with a description of the context, what I would like the ideal situation to be and what I've tried so far.

**Context**

I am trying to build a straight-forward React application using Webpack. I will refer to this application as **core**. On top of this, there is an optional **branding** that can be bundled by Webpack which looks at a given branding directory, grabs assets and transpiles custom SASS using it's own loaders and output strategy. It then overrides the default assets used by core with the branding specific ones (think favicons, logo's, backdrops).

The structure is as follows:

I have several webpack config files,

- webpack.dev.js *--Config specifying env and dev-server configurations and merges this with core & branding*
- webpack.prod.js *--Small config specifying env and minification plugins and merges this with core & branding*
- webpack.branding.js *--Declares branding specific bundling rules & merges with generic*
- webpack.core.js *--Declares core specific bundling rules & merges with generic*
- webpack.generic.js *--Provides generic configuration that both branding and core use*

The source for these files in the current situation can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pnobbe/41caf8a90be2b621a44aa3b69f10a78a).

**Ideal situation**

Core should be able to function entirely on it's own, using default assets. When a dev/prod build process is started it will run both core and branding unless specifically told to run one exclusively.

Branding should also be able to build on it's own, resulting in a small package containing only branding assets. The process should be flexible enough so that a branding dist should be able to replace any files in a dist core folder without core having to recompile and rebuild references. For now, these assets are limited to a CSS file (branding.css) and some image assets.

**What I have tried**

- I have tried using the using the built-in [Webpack multicompiler](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler) to run core and branding at the same time (`module.exports = [core, branding]`), but I am unable to dictate the order that Webpack runs the core and branding processes in because it runs them in parallel. Since the branding process is much smaller it will always finish first, causing branding assets to be overwritten by defaults instead.
- I have tried using [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge) to merge the core and branding configuration files, but this does not work because I specify different output rules for both. Core uses contenthashes in it's output naming convention, while branding does not. This does not play nice when trying to merge together. I will either get two of each file when using `merge.multiple()`, one with hash and one without, or I will only get one of each file dictated by a single configuration when using `merge.smart()`, either with hash or without hash (depending on merge order).
- I have tried running core and branding in sequence from my npm scripts using the `&&` command (`"build": "webpack --config webpack.core.js && webpack --config webpack.branding.js --branding <brand>"`). This does not work in tandem with the webpack-dev-server.

Thanks in advance for any help and/or advice. I will update my question with more information if necessary.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this? I have the exact same requirements (running two configs in sequence, with webpack-dev-server support).

Comment: The worst is that the documentation says that MultiCompiler should run in *sequence*, not in parallel! Something seems off... https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#multicompiler

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not a direct answer to you question, but I'm leaving this here to help others with an issue that looks exactly the same as yours on the surface:

I *thought* I had the exact same issue because my "app" config (which uses `DllPlugin` to reference its "lib" bundle) failed building because its "lib" dependency's DLL manifest wasn't generated yet. This led me to think that maybe configs were run in parallel and not sequentially like the webpack documentation says (this felt weird, but bugs do happen sometimes).

However (and I think this was exacerbated by the fact that my two configs were in separate files), I failed to immediately notice an important detail: the actual config itself is loaded instantly, *not* when it's time to build. Thus, my `DllReferencePlugin` config tried to load the DLL manifest instantly, before any of the configs were run:

```
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  manifest: require(path.join(tempDir, "/lib.dll-manifest.json"))
}),
```

Luckily, the `manifest` option allows passing a path instead of pre-loading a manifest object. Using an absolute path allows `DllReferencePlugin` to load the manifest only when the config runs:

```
new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
  manifest: path.join(tempDir, "/lib.dll-manifest.json")
}),
```

In retrospect this was such a small, "obvious" thing. But it was easy to miss inside large webpack configs.

So if you have an issue similar to this, it may be that your dependent webpack configurations require stuff too early, before the dependencies have a chance to generate the files themselves. Stepping in the build script and webpack config using node's `--inspect-brk` and a debugger (VS Code's) helped me find the root cause.

---

As an aside, I've also seen mentions of the `name` and `dependencies` config options, but didn't find much (if any) information about them in the documentation:

```
const configA = {
  name: "lib",
  entry: ...
  ...
}

const configB = {
  name: "app",
  dependencies: ["lib"]
  entry: ...
  ...
}
```

[This](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5907) and [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/8a7597aa6eb2eef66a8f9db3a0c49bcb96022a94/lib/MultiCompiler.js#L93) proves the feature exists, even though it's not mentioned in the documentation. <del>You might be able to define the build order that you want this way, although I didn't test it.</del> In the end it seems like this is also an important part of the puzzle. Without the `name` and `dependencies` properties it seems like webpack assumes it can run the configs in parallel, at least as of webpack 4.25.1.